# Get all children of a Godot Node with specific type in C#

Tags: c#, generics, godot, godot4

I need to find all children of a Godot node with specific type in C# and return them as Godot.Collections.Array. But it seems using Generics with Array is not possible(or maybe I don't know how to do it). Here is two attempts I did both not working:

1:

```
public static Array<T> GetChildren<T>(Node _node) where T : Node
    {
        return _node.GetChildren().Where(x => x is T).ToArray();
    }
```

which results in this error: "The non-generic type 'Array' cannot be used with type arguments"
2:

```
public static Array GetChildren<T>(Node _node) where T : Node
    {
        var foundNodes = _node.GetChildren();
        var results = new Godot.Collections.Array();
        foreach (var nd in foundNodes)
            if (nd is T) results.Add(nd as T);
        return foundNodes;
    }
```

which gives me this error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'Godot.Collections.Array<Godot.Node>' to 'System.Array'"

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it:

```
public static Variant GetChildren<T>(Node _node) where T : Node
    {
        return _node.GetChildren().Where(x => x is T).ToArray();
    }
```

I used "Variant" as the function type but the downside is I have to cast the result every time I use it. like this:

```
Results = (Array<NodeType>)GetChildren<NodeType>(this);
```

So I'm not sure if there's still a better solution.

Comment: If you want to return `Array<T>` and this works `(Array<NodeType>)GetChildren<NodeType>(this)`, I would expect `return (Array<T>)(_node.GetChildren().Where(x => x is T).ToArray());` to work. Does it not? - Addenum: If I recall correctly `ToArray` can take type argument: `return _node.GetChildren().Where(x => x is T).ToArray<T>();` although that would not be Godot's `Array`.

Comment: Casting like that in GetChildren<T>(...) doesn't work(error: "Cannot convert type 'Godot.Node[]' to 'Godot.Collections.Array<T>':). Changing the return type of GetChildren<T>(...) from Variant to Array<T> also doesn't(error: "The generic type parameter must be annotated with the MustBeVariant attribute"). Changing "Where T : Node" to "Where T : Variant" also doesn't(error: "'Variant' is not a valid constraint. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter.").